# Externalising code from Javascript Initialize function does not work?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am trying to build polygons with Google maps V3 but I got this problem: when I put my piece of code in my initialize function, it works ... but when I externalise it, it does not work.

This is my code:

```
function AddSecteurs() {
    var Secteur ;
    var SecteurCoords = [
            new google.maps.LatLng(47.216770, -1.553879 ),
            new google.maps.LatLng(47.516770, -1.563879 ),
            new google.maps.LatLng(47.216770, -1.574579 ),
            new google.maps.LatLng(47.216770, -1.5744179),
            new google.maps.LatLng(47.216770, -1.584579 ),
            new google.maps.LatLng(47.236770, -1.574579 ),
            new google.maps.LatLng(47.229770, -1.574579 )];
    Secteur = new google.maps.Polygon({
      paths: SecteurCoords,
      strokeColor: "#FF0000",
      strokeOpacity: 0.8,
      strokeWeight: 2,
      fillColor: "#FF0000",
      fillOpacity: 0.35,
    });
    Secteur.setMap(map);
}
```

Comment: the part that is in that function.

Comment: in fact, this function got the code i just externalize, this code was in the Initiliaze function of my file

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're missing the `map` variable in your function.

Just declare it as a parameter:

```
function AddSecteurs(map) ...
```

And pass it to the new function from the `Initialize` function:

```
AddSecteur(map);
```